# How to get first non zero value and last non zero value indexes in array?

Tags: php

Ok So I have an PHP array of data like the following

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
500 // Get index of this value which is 6
11000
100
110
221
1245
2141// Get index of this value which is 12
0
0
0
0
0
```

Is there a PHP function that would grab the **first Non-Zero Value index** and the **last Non-Zero value index**? Or a very beautiful way to do it?

I know I can do this with a few `IF` statements, but it will become very messy.

Comment: Should't the index for value 500 be 6?

Comment: @lloiacono yes :P thanks for pointing out the schoolboy error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

**Demo**: [Link](https://3v4l.org/nACHe)

```
$array = [0,0,0,0,0,0,500 ,11000,100,110,221,1245,2141,0,0,0,0,0];

$result = array_filter($array); // it will filter false values 

echo key($result); // 6
end($result); // set pointer to end of the array
echo key($result); // 12
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution with single `array_reduce()` function:

```
$arr = [0,0,0,0,0,0,500 ,11000,100,110,221,1245,2141,0,0,0,0,0];

$result = array_reduce($arr, function($r, $v) use (&$c){
    if ($v) $r[($r? 1:0)] = $c;
    $c++;
    return $r;
}, []);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 12
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and then `reset()` and `end()`.

> If no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed.

```
$a = [
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    500 ,
    11000,
    100,
    110,
    221,
    1245,
    2141,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
];
$filteredArray = array_filter($a);

$firstNonZeroKey = key($filteredArray);
end($filteredArray);
$lastNonZeroKey = key($filteredArray);
```

`array_filter()` removes `0`, `false` and `''` values by default

Comment: Thanks for the answer!